# Python 2.7 crashes when importing PyQt4.QtDeclarative or PyQt4.Qt on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt4, python-sip, qtdeclarative

Some time ago (months?) the program `rqt_plot` started crashing on startup (SIGSEGV) on my machine.  I finally tracked it down a little deeper and found that the problem occurs while python is trying to import `PyQt4.QtDeclarative`.  Unfortunately I don't remember when this started happening, and my Internet searches have turned up nothing.  Any ideas what's going wrong?  I suspect an incompatible package update somewhere along the way, but have no idea how to find the root cause.

Here's a simple session transcript:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4 import QtDeclarative
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

Here's some system information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux [HOSTNAME] 3.13.0-63-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14 21:42:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ echo $PYTHONPATH

$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan  8  2015 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

Follow-up:

I found later that I had the same problem (Segmentation fault) when doing `import PyQt4.Qt` as well.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `python-qt4` using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-qt4`? Just curious to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, try the above `apt-get install python-qt4`, might make a difference

Comment: @edwinksl  My linux-fu is weak; Yours is strong!  A simple reinstall was all that was required.  If you post an "Answer" in addition to your comment, I'll award you the bounty.  It was well worth it!  =:-D

Comment: @aldo Ah, glad to see that a simple solution works. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be difficult to diagnose a segfault when the only error message is

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

In this case, because reinstallation of `python-qt4` does not take much time at all, I would recommend you do it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-qt4
```

Edit: It looks like OP encountered another segfault when doing `import PyQt4.Qt`. This is probably related to `python-sip`, which is a dependency of `python-pyqt4`. To get rid of the segfault, reinstall `python-sip` by running:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-sip
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this first.  I tried removing extra, "unused" packages, upgrading the kernel, pulling my hair out...  skipped the obvious solution.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @aldo That happens to all of us. :)

Comment: Ok, that solved most of my problem, but now `import PyQt4.Qt` gives me the same segfault.  Gah!

Comment: @aldo That is bewildering. The reinstallation would have reinstalled `Qt.so` (along with `QtDeclarative.so`), so I am not sure what is going on at this point.

Comment: @aldo It might be worthwhile reinstalling `python-sip`: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-sip`.

Comment: @aldo Ah nice, let me update my answer to reflect that. :D